# Can I use Jegantha as a companion if I have an Apex creature in my deck because of the Alternate cost?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm building a mutate deck and since the deck meets the conditions for [Jegantha, the Wellspring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJegantha%2c%20the%20Wellspring%5d) I wanted to use it, but since I'm running a few of the Apex creatures and their mutate costs don't meet the requirement I wanted to know if Jegantha also looks at alternate costs or if it only looks at base cost for the requirement.

Answer (score 5):

The mutate costs don't matter; you can still use Jegantha as your Companion. Jegantha states:

> No card in your starting deck has more than one of the same mana symbol in its mana cost.

Mana cost is defined in the rules:

> 202.1. A card’s mana cost is indicated by mana symbols near the top of the card.

Costs of other abilities that may appear on a card, including mutate costs, are not the mana cost of the card itself, and that is all Jegantha is looking at.